# Upload javascript blob wav file and compress

Tags: javascript, html, audio, asp.net-web-api2, html5-audio

I'm using [Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) lib to record audio from browser, so, I have the wav blob on some variable.
To upload to the server, i'm using `FormData` converting blob to base64 string:

```
var reader = new FileReader();                    

reader.onload = function (event) {
    toUpload.append("audio", event.target.result);
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig); // my ajax call
}

reader.readAsDataURL(myBlob);
```

When the file reaches to the server, i'm using NAudio.Lame to compress to mp3 format ([recordjsmp3](https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js) is very slow, want to do it on server-side):

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(myFile))
using (var wav = new WaveFileReader(ms))
```

.net throws the exception:

```
FormatException: Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header
```

Ok, let's try to save the file on disk to play on Windows Media Player:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.wav", myFile);
```

When I try to play the file saved on disk, media player says that file is corrupted.

My endpoint is Asp.Net web api, and i'm doing this to take the byte array:

```
var multipart = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
multipart.Contents.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.ToLower().Contains("audio")).ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you just upload the blob without base64? also, where does the blob come from (specifically, what command)?

Comment: @dandavis this is the answer! lol tks